# tcolorbox incompatibe with color package?

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I am trying to add a `tcolorbox` into my Xelatex document but it does not seem to work. I tracked the problem to the `color` package which if disabled produces the box. However I need to use the `color` package.

How can I work around this?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Uncomment the next line to get the error
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,title=A nice heading]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load the package before `tcolorbox` but load `xcolor` rather than `color`. The same options will work.

Comment: Have you tried with the package `xcolor`?

Comment: @Dox Yes. Have you? The problem is the loading order. Because the OP is passing options to the package and `tcolorbox` loads the package without those options, there's a clash. You need all the options to be passed at once to the package. Loading the package first works fine. `xcolor` is recommended but it isn't the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`xcolor` is an enhanced version of `color` but the real trick here is simply to load it *first*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,title=A nice heading]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: box back]

Answer (score 5):

`tcolorbox` loads `pgf` which loads `xcolor` without options. If you want to pass some options to `xcolor` (which completely integrates `color` functionality) you can use cfr solution `\usepackage[]{xcolor}` with specific options before loading `tcolorbox`, but you also have two more options.

The first one would be to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` which passes options `usenames` and `dvipsnames` whenever `xcolor` is loaded.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=JungleGreen!5, colframe=JungleGreen!40!black, title=A nice heading]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

And a second one consists in passing these options through `\documentclass` because from
page 17 in LaTeX Companion, 2ed:

> All options to `\documentclass` (both declared and global ones) are
>   automatically passed as class options to all `\usepackage`
>   declarations. Thus, if a package file loaded with a `\usepackage`
>   declaration recognizes (i.e. declares) some of the class options, it
>   can take appropriate actions. If not, the class options will be
>   ignores while processing that package.

As a simple test, I've changed `green` to `JungleGreen` (in `dvipsnames` list) in your example and tried with

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article} %<--- usenames is an obsolete option. deleted.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=JungleGreen!5, colframe=JungleGreen!40!black, title=A nice heading]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

which works without problems:

[image]