# error: option clash for package xcolor

Tags: errors, color

When trying to load I get the error message 'Option clash for package xcolor'. I have already understood that this is because other packages I loaded before also automatically load this package. All I need to know is which package does this, such that I can put the 'xcolor' option in the command. My preamable is below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=2.5cm,
arrow line width=0.2cm
}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Insured \\ policy holder,Insurer \\ company}
}
```

Comment: First , you don't need `\usepackage{tikz}` as `tikz` is loaded by `smartdiagram`, so remove it. Second, load `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{smartdiagram}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding out which package loads what is often a daunting task. Instead pass the options before document class. If there is still an option clash then you cannot use that option together with the other package loading. Also `smartdiagram -> tikz -> {graphicx,xcolor}`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{float}

\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=2.5cm,
arrow line width=0.2cm
}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Insured \\ policy holder,Insurer \\ company}
}
\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or pass conflicting options to `\documentclass` as [I've discovered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238324/1952) today

Comment: It's the case one has to do that when loading `pstricks` and `xcolor` with options that are not loaded by pstricks.