# How to make box around the figure equal to the length of the textwidth?

Tags: pdftex

The problem is that the size of the box is greater than textwidth which is not looking good in my thesis. I want box not to exceed the textwidth.
Below are the packages I included in my latex file and the code for including figures.

I have no idea, how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFigureBoxStyle}{tikzsetting={draw=black, line width=1pt}}%
\makeatletter
  \newcommand\fs@myRoundBox{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\begin{mdframed}[style=myFigureBoxStyle]}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \def\@fs@post{\end{mdframed}}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\floatstyle{myRoundBox} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep]{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have read solutions suggested earlier and based on the solutions, I tried many options such as `\fbox`, `\framebox`, `\resizebox`, etc. but could not get the desired result. Either I get two boxes or the error.

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this solution with the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float, caption}
\floatstyle{boxed}
 \usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\setlength{\FrameRule}{1pt}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period}
\begin{framed}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep]{venus-mars-and-cupid}
\captionof{figure}{Piero di Cosimo: Venus, Mars and Cupid (1505)}
\label{fig:f2}
\end{framed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the use of the `tcolorbox` is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=30mm,vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor} % had to be loaded before "tcolorbox"
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black,colback=white,colupper=red!50!black}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Figure 1}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{Figure 2}
\label{fig:f2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: I am getting an error -"! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor."

Comment: @TriptiAgrawal, you neeed to lod `xcolor` before `tcolorbox`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238303/tcolorbox-incompatibe-with-color-package. In edited answer i add `xcolor` package.

Comment: There is a small typo in the code. Use `\usepackage{xcolor} instead of `\usepsckage{xcolor}`.

Comment: @projetmbc, corrected. thank you to point me on error.

Comment: Now getting error as - "! Package caption Error: \caption outside float."

Comment: @TriptiAgrawal, I don't know what you doing. My MWE propose two solution and both works without any  warning or error, i.e. in both cases captions are inside float `figure`.

Comment: Zarko, I know as I have tried your code independently, and they are working fine. However, in my thesis, several packages are included, few of them are creating problems. Thanks a lot!